# Asterisk Background function not playing ivr as expected

Tags: asterisk

Hi I am trying to play IVR in background during call. I have no need ringing sound. I have tried as following  so far

extensions.conf file

```
exten => _X.,1,Progress()
exten => _X.,2,Background(you_have&minutes&dollar&you_have&dollar)
exten => _X.,3,AGI(mybilling.php)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup
```

Its not working. It working like `Playback()` and call starting (initiating) after ivr finished.

**I need play this IVR background while call is being sent to user**

Any idea regarding playing background music will be appreciated.

I have tried `m` option with `DIAL()` but no idea how to play ivr instead default file.
I am using phpagi where ivr playing by agi script.

If anyone can solve this issue using agi script also acceptable. asterisk version 1.8

Comment: How is your issue related to PHP?

Answer (score 2):

I think you not readed carefully what it do.

It work ONLY with waitExten after it.

i.e if you do like this

```
exten =>s,1,Background(file)
same => n,WaitExten(5);wait upt 5 sec, STILL PLAY FILE

exten => 1,1,Noop(1 pressed)
```

then it works.

No any other variant.

To do like you want need play with conference bridge or chanspy in additional channel.